# CORS method not found for DELETE request on Django (preflight request)

Tags: django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

In my django app I'm getting a CORS error only for DELETE requests. In the dev tools, it says that it didn't find the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header, but yet I can see under the Network tab in the browser, that the header is indeed set, with a value of '*'. It says: access-control-allow-methods '*'.

I checked in the settings file for django, and I've set the cors middleware (I've removed a few that I deemed unnecessary since I'm just using the rest framework.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

I've also doubled checked the CORS settings and everything seems to be in order there too:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'https://localhost:3001',
    'https://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost',
]
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    'Set-Cookie',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I've also double checked the logs for the reverse proxy and the request is being forwarded to the api just fine, so no issue there. The request runs just fine if I send it in a curl request, but something about the OPTIONS preflight request isn't correct and I can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it had to do with the fact that the cors policy was being enforce on my traefik reverse proxy. After fixing it there, everything worked.